# Maximum number of words found in sentences

Tags: c++, algorithm

> You are given an array of strings sentences, where each sentences[i]
> represents a single sentence. Return the maximum number of words that appear in a single sentence.
>
> **Example**
> **Input:** sentences = ["alice and bob love leetcode", "i think so too", "this is great thanks very much"]
> **Output:** 6
> **Explanation:** The first sentence has 5 words, second sentence has 4 words, third sentence has 6 words, so the maximum number of words is 6.

My program:

```
int mostWordsFound(vector<string>& sentences) {
    int n = sentences.size();
    int max = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        int counter = 0;
        for (int j = 0; j < sentences[i].size(); j++) {
            if (sentences[i][j] == ' ') counter++;
        }
        if (max < counter) max = counter;
    }
    return max + 1;
}
```

My program's output is correct, but the time complexity is O(n^2), are there any other ways to improve this program? Thanks.

Comment: You are assuming words are separated by a single space. Maybe all the test data is; but I would not assume that about real world data. Also you have not considered punctuation will that effect words?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Time Complexity

First of all, your time complexity is not `O(n^2)`. You only have one loop going from `0` to `n` and then loop over each character. So your time complexity rather looks like `O(n*k)`. I don't think it can be any faster, since you need to check every string and every character.

## Using namespace std

I think it's really terrible that leetcode does this by default. [Read this link on why it's considered bad practice.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice)

## ref vs const ref

You're taking the array as a ref, but not as a const ref. Since you're not altering it in any way, you should take it as a const ref.

## .size() does not return an int

```
int n = sentences.size();
```

the return type of `std::vector::size()` is `std::size_t`. Converting it to an int might narrow it (for long vectors) and the size can never be negative anyway.

## Use range-based for loops

You do not even need to store the size, just use range based for loops:

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>

int mostWordsFound(std::vector<std::string> const& sentences) {    
    int max = 0;

    for( auto const& sentence : sentences ){
        int counter{0};
        for( auto const& character : sentence ){
            if( character == ' '){
                counter++;
            }
        }
        max = counter > max? counter : max;
    }
    return max+1;    
}
```

## A Bug?

You are assuming that the input somehow makes sense. But consider the following code:

```
int main(){
    std::cout << mostWordsFound({"Hello World!", "Hello    World\n"}) << "\n";
}
```

This will output `5`, because of all the consecutive whitespaces. A way to improve this program would be to check, if the previous character was a whitespace also, and  then not count the current whitespace. Also, trailing or leading whitespaces will give a wrong result (or imagine a string of only spaces!).

Comment: In the for loop, why did you use the `const&` keyword after `auto` ?

Comment: If you do not use it, each loop iteration will create a copy. You can also drop the  `const` and just use a ref, if you want to alter elements while iterating.

Comment: I think altering elements while iterating is not possible according to this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6438086/iterator-invalidation-rules-for-c-containers

Comment: You understood it wrong. You can alter the elements, but you can not / should not erase or add elements while iterating. [See this example here](https://godbolt.org/z/E7Mdfqrox)